# BubbleSort for Object type of array is not working perfectly

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to ask about bubblesort (Java)

Here's my code

```
Object[] bubbled = {"LMAO", 3.48 ,2.3 ,3.61 ,3.16 ,3.56 ,2.9 ,3.99 ,4.87 ,3.91};
for(int pass=1 ; pass<bubbled.length-1;pass++){
            for(int i=1;i<bubbled.length-1-pass;i++){
                if(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(bubbled[i]))> 
                    Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(bubbled[i+1]))){
                    float hold= Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(bubbled[i]));
                    bubbled[i] = bubbled[i+1];
                    bubbled[i+1] = hold;
                } 
            }
        }
```

The array is `Object[]` type. and I want it to start at `bubbled[1]` since `bubbled[0]` is non-numeric value.
It does the sorting but not to my last 3 index at the end of the process.

For example:

Before : `3.48 ,2.3 ,3.61 ,3.16 ,3.56 ,2.9 ,3.99 ,4.87 ,3.91`

After : `2.3 ,2.9 ,3.16,3.48 ,3.56, 3.61 ,3.99, 4.87 ,3.91`

Can someone please point out what's wrong ?

Comment: I seems to me like a great opportunity to learn using a debugger. Did you try that?

Comment: Don't convert to a string and back to a double to compare numeric values: check if they *are* numeric values (using e.g. `instanceof Number`), then cast the pair to `Number` and compare using `.doubleValue()`. Aside from anything, you're changing the values here by using `float` to store the `hold` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making enough passes over the array.

```
for(int pass = 0; pass < bubbled.length; pass++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you forgot the last iteration in each for loop.
change your for loops to:

```
for(int pass=1 ; pass<bubbled.length;pass++){
            for(int i=1;i<bubbled.length-pass;i++){
```

and that should work just fine